# What does last output parameter of command lsusb -t means?

Tags: linux, usb

Question 
What does  **last output parameter of command `lsusb -t` mean**?

In example, parameter `12M`

```
Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bus speed, you can confirm it by reading "speed" file.

```
cs-server@:~/Downloads/logs$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/speed 
480
cs-server@:~/Downloads/logs$ 
cs-server@:~/Downloads/logs$ 
cs-server@:~/Downloads/logs$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
cs-server@:~/Downloads/logs$
```